# Jquery Mobile headers not displaying in the app

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm building an iphone app in Phonegap and jQuery Mobile. Using very basic elements so far, but my headers are not displaying in the xcode iphone simulator (see the screen shot). Anyone knows what the issue might be?

Here is the html structure I've used: http://pastebin.com/czRyhRhM

[image: Screen shot of the app in Chrome and iphone simulator]

Comment: Could be just about anything. Have you tried opening it as a regular website in mobile safari?

Comment: Could you provide the code you are testing with?

Comment: Sorry for the very late response; I've edited my question to point to the html structure I've used. Thanks.